# Two independent timers

Tags: javascript

I can't understand. Wrote code for 2 independent timers. But when you press the start button, both timers start. What am I doing wrong, tell me?

I tried with conditions, but it didn't work. Maybe we can somehow solve this? I don't have any ideas anymore.
Here is the code:

```js
const res = document.getElementById('res'),
  btnStart = document.getElementById('start'),
  btnStop = document.getElementById('stop');

const res1 = document.getElementById('res1'),
  btnStart1 = document.getElementById('start1'),
  btnStop1 = document.getElementById('stop1');


function getCounter(el, startBtn, stopBtn) {
  let sec = 0;
  let min = 0;
  let hours = 0;
  let interval;
  let isAvtive = false;

  function updateCounter() {
    sec++;
    if (sec === 60) {
      min++;
      sec = 0;
    }
    if (min === 60) {
      hours++;
      min = 0;
    }
    if (hours === 24) {
      hours = 0;
    }
    el.textContent = sec;
    if (btnStart) {
      res.textContent = `${hours.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${min.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${sec.toString().padStart(2,0)}`;
    }
    if (btnStart1) {
      res1.textContent = `${hours.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${min.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${sec.toString().padStart(2,0)}`;
    }

  }

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (btnStart)
      interval = setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);


  });
  stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = null;

    }
  })


}


getCounter(res, btnStart, btnStop);
getCounter(res1, btnStart1, btnStop1);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" />
<span id="res"></span>

<br/>

<input type="button" value="start1" id="start1" />
<input type="button" value="stop1" id="stop1" />
<span id="res1"></span>
```

Comment: `if(btnStart)` and `if(btnStart1)` both always pass and both always execute the code inside the `if`. Therefore, there is no difference which button you click - `updateCounter` will go through and update both.

Comment: Yes. But why? If I press only one button. Why does the second one pass?

Comment: `if(btnStart)` is always true because: `btnStart = document.getElementById('start')`

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to climb. It seems that I just processed it and my brains floated :)

Comment: `if(btnStart)` essentially means "if the button exists" not "if the button was pressed"

Answer (score 1):

```js
const res = document.getElementById('res');
const btnStart = document.getElementById('start');
const btnStop = document.getElementById('stop');

const res1 = document.getElementById('res1');
const btnStart1 = document.getElementById('start1');
const btnStop1 = document.getElementById('stop1');

function getCounter(el, startBtn, stopBtn) {
  let sec = 0;
  let min = 0;
  let hours = 0;
  let interval;
  let isActive = false;

  function updateCounter() {
    sec++;
    if (sec === 60) {
      min++;
      sec = 0;
    }
    if (min === 60) {
      hours++;
      min = 0;
    }
    if (hours === 24) {
      hours = 0;
    }
    el.textContent = `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${min.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${sec.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!isActive) {
      interval = setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
      isActive = true;
    }
  });

  stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      isActive = false;
    }
  });
}

getCounter(res, btnStart, btnStop);
getCounter(res1, btnStart1, btnStop1);
```

```html
<p>Result: <span id="res">00:00:00</span></p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>

<p>Result1: <span id="res1">00:00:00</span></p>
<button id="start1">Start1</button>
<button id="stop1">Stop1</button>
```

Inside the updateCounter function, the isActive flag is used to determine whether the timer has started. The timer is only started if isActive is false. This allows each timer to be controlled independently of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function to create a timer in a parent element, you can provide a HTML template and insert it instead of repeating it in HTML.

Don't use `setInterval/setTimeout` since they aren't precise and throttled in inactive tabs. Just calculate difference between start and current time. For smooth display use `requestAnimationFrame()` so your display would be also precise:

```js
function createTimer(parent = document.body){

  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="timer">
    <h1 class="text" style="font-family:monospace"></h1>
    <button class="start">Start</button>
    <button class="stop">Stop</button>
  </div>`);
  
  const $timer = [...parent.children].at(-1);

  let start, today, running;
  
  const [$text, $start, $stop] = 'text start stop'.split(' ').map(name => $timer.querySelector('.' + name));

  $start.onclick = () => {
    start = new Date, today = new Date;
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    running = true;
    timer();
  };
  
  $stop.onclick = () => running = false;
  
  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    hourCycle: 'h23',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',  
    fractionalSecondDigits: 2
  });

  $text.textContent = '00:00:00.00';

  // add today's timestamp so the timezone would be properly handled
  const timer = () => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    $text.textContent = format.format(new Date - start + +today);
    running && timer();
  });
}

const container = document.querySelector('.timers');

createTimer(container);
createTimer(container);
createTimer(container);
```

```css
button{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:lightblue;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:3px;
}
.timers{
  display:flex;
}
.timers > *{
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="timers"></div>
```